# Apt update fails with Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: updates, apt, ubuntu, elementary-project, surface-tablet

Issue:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -y

Err:1 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 libwacom-surface amd64 1.12-2
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:2 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-surface-secureboot-mok amd64 20211103-1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/86019e52-7bfa-4bc6-8cc1-52147027aee6?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20211103/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211103T233837Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=055b509fac7b8b7008dd9b9ebaffe3d58479e71eb4e739557bb581c66c16a2a6&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom-surface_1.12-2_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/211351605/1d335c4a-7dab-43d5-b588-fcaeeeddf6d9?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20211103/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211103T233838Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=aba11808b0a296208d160a4d94601c5a29c5d8b2d3c73d22f7e7c9eb421b04da&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=211351605&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-surface-secureboot-mok_20211103-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The Surface Linux community has had trouble upgrading or updating specific packages. They found that apt is not encoding special characters properly.

```
bad:  https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/86019e52-7bfa-4bc6-8cc1-52147027aee6?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20211105/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211105T161053Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=2bc0c28946db539ada250b1030c37249dae909d73a68c90b5e7bfe7fecd5d347&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom-surface_1.12-2_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream


good: https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/86019e52-7bfa-4bc6-8cc1-52147027aee6?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211105%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211105T160935Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=44d9307e66dfb5b3672ee0082b8801ad2532ac4b6be61c3442fb265ffce72852&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dlibwacom-surface_1.12-2_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
```

Several special characters have been encoded in the second ("good") link. To verify this, I ran apt install libwacom-surface, took the failing link from that, and encoded the special characters in the places where they were encoded in the "good" link. Plugging that into wget works.

So it seems that there's something wrong with the way apt handles special characters in some links (after all, wget gets this right)
Works with apt version 2.2.x, Ubuntu 20.04 (which I used to test in those comments) however uses 2.0.x.

All of this is text from github comments about the issue.

Testing and quoted text from StollD and qzed on github.

Link to the original discussion: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/625

Right now we can wget the packages. Has anyone else received this error within the last week using apt?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried for the solution, since I am from India, so I tried to remove the "in." eg. "deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted" many other lines were also there but we have to target deb http://in.archive .... to deb http://archive.... means we have to remove "in." from all the lines.
After that just run the commands below
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

```
  then start
```

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
& apt autoremove

```
  .............that's it folks & your system upgrades.......
```

IT WORKED FOR ME........ MIGHT HELP YOU ALL TOO......BEST OF LUCK......